# PowerPoint 2013, set default layout, presentation, or similar

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

when PowerPoint opens, I would like for it to show me a blank presentation with no preformatted text boxes like the following, preferably with multiple blank slides (use case below):

[image]

Currently, it starts with some text boxes like this:

[image]

I've searched the net and the settings and I have not found anything that seems to do what I want.  I have looked into changing the [default theme/template](https://superuser.com/questions/892101/where-is-powerpoints-equivalent-of-words-normal-dotm) and [setting a default layout](https://superuser.com/questions/548038/change-default-slide-layout-in-powerpoint#637148).  The default theme/template seems to require that you click on the "Blank" in the start screen, and I can't seem to get the [add-in from SKP](http://skp.mvps.org/setlayout.htm) to work.  I guess it's not compatible, or Outlook 2013 doesn't do *.PPA files anymore.

Is there a way to do what I want to do?  I will be upgrading to PowerPoint 2016 soon, if that changes anything.

**Use Case**

I find it advantageous to use PowerPoint as a place to keep screenshots during tech support calls.  This is my primary purpose in using PowerPoint, and only occasionally do I make presentations with it.  However, if and when I do make presentations, i would still want to start with a blank canvas.

Comment: The solution from the first link you provided worked for me. Made a ppt with 3 blank pages and save it as a .potx in the Roaming folder. Now everytime I open PowerPoint the 3 blank slides appear.

Comment: Re: your Use Case - have you ever considered using MicroSoft One Note instead? You can paste in screenshots, type stuff, paste text from webpages and it also keeps a note of where you got it from. Might be a better fit than a presentation tool that you never make presentations in?

Comment: OneNote is not guarenteed to be on other peoples machines if I need to send the screenshots, and last I used it, was a performance hog.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint still works with PPA add-ins as of Office 2016, but if that add-in hasn't been updated for the multiple layout object model introduced in PPT 2007, it might well not work.

Your simplest solution might be to create a "starter" PPT with a bunch of pre-made blank slides in it, then put a shortcut to it on your desktop or wherever it's convenient/easily accessible.  Start a new presentation by doubleclicking that, then save to a new name if needed.